# Aparecer botão conforme a condição do parâmetro php

Tags: php, html, if, button

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o botão aparecer somente se o parametro for verdadeiro.
Pela URL vem o parametro `../usuario?id=1&parametro=1`

Tentei dessa forma mas não consegui

```html
<?php 

$parametro = $_GET['Parametro'];

if ($parametro == 1){
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded"> <a href="editando_usuario?id=<? echo $_GET['id']?>" style="color: #ffffff"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>  Editar</a></button>
}
?>
```

Então, o botão só apareceria se o `($parametro == 1)`. É possível fazer isso com o botão ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro receba o parâmetro e já verifique se o mesmo foi setado. Isso porque o usuário (intencionalmente ou não) pode remover o parâmetro e isso pode disparar um erro ou causar um comportamento inadequado na aplicação (Recomendo pesquisar sobre Programação defensiva, XSS, SQL Injection e Tamper Data).

Nesse caso foi utilizado um operador ternário (que funciona como um IF rápido). Caso o valor tenha sido passado é armazenado na variável $param e caso tenha sido omitido da URL o valor zero é gravado na variável.

```
<?php $param = isset($_GET['parametro']) ? $_GET['parametro'] : 0; ?>
```

Depois no seu HTML check se o parâmetro é igual a um.
Note também que foi utilizado uma notação para o IF mais apropriada para o HTML. Ao invés de espalhar fechamentos de chaves no HTML você terá um endif que é muito mais amigável.

```
<?php if($param == 1): ?>
    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded"> <a href="editando_usuario?id=<? echo $_GET['id']?>" style="color: #ffffff"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>  Editar</a></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maravilha, muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 3):

Com operador ternário:

```
$button = $_GET['parametro']==1 ? '<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded"> <a href="editando_usuario?id="'.$_GET['id'].'" style="color: #ff0000"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>  Editar</a></button>' : "";
echo $button;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

É só você quebrar o seu bloco de php ou então escrever html do trecho como uma string.

```
$parametro = $_GET['Parametro'];

if ($parametro == 1){
?>
     <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded">
         <a href="editando_usuario?id=<? echo $_GET['id']?>" style="color: #ffffff"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Editar</a>
     </button>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer dessa forma.